# Is a functional language a good choice for a Flight Simulator? How about Lisp?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, simulation

I have been doing object-oriented programming for a few years now, and I have not done much functional programming. I have an interest in flight simulators, and am curious about the functional programming aspect of Lisp. Flight simulators or any other real world simulator makes sense to me in an object-oriented paradigm.

Here are my questions:

Is object oriented the best way to represent a real world simulation domain?

I know that Common Lisp has CLOS (OO for lisp), but my question is really about writing a flight simulator in a functional language.  So if you were going to write it in Lisp, would you choose to use CLOS or write it in a functional manner?

Does anyone have any thoughts on coding a flight simulator in lisp or any functional language?

UPDATE 11/8/12 - A similar SO question for those interested -> [How does functional programming apply to simulations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431654/how-does-functional-programming-apply-to-simulations)

Comment: check this out: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~pls/thesis/munc-thesis.pdf

Answer (score 12):

It's a common mistake to think of "Lisp" as a functional language.  Really it is best thought of as a family of languages,  probably, but these days when people say Lisp they usually mean Common Lisp.

Common Lisp allows functional programming, but it isn't a functional language per se.  Rather it is a general purpose language.  Scheme is a much smaller variant, that is more functional in orientation, and of course there are others.

As for your question is it a good choice?  That really depends on your plans.  Common Lisp particularly has some real strengths for this sort of thing.  It's both interactive and introspective at a level you usually see in so-called scripting languages, making it very quick to develop in.  At the same time its compiled and has efficient compilers, so you can expect performance in the same ballpark as other efficient compilers (with a factor of two of c is typical ime). While a large language, it has a much more consistent design than things like c++, and the metaprogramming capabilities can make very clean, easy to understand code for your particular application. If you only look at these aspects
common lisp looks amazing.

However, there are downsides.  The community is small, you won't find many people to help if that's what you're looking for.  While the built in library is large, you won't find as many 3rd party libraries, so you may end up writing more of it from scratch.  Finally, while it's by no means a walled garden, CL doesn't have the kind of smooth integration with foreign libraries that say python does.  Which doesn't mean you can't call c code, there are nice tools for this.

By they way, CLOS is about the most powerful OO system I can think of, but it is quite a different approach if you're coming from a mainstream c++/java/c#/etc. OO background (yes, they differ, but beyond single vs. multiple inh. not that much)  you may find it a bit strange at first, almost turned inside out.

If you go this route, you are going to have to watch for some issues with performance of the actual rendering pipeline, if you write that yourself with CLOS.  The class system has incredible runtime flexibility (i.e. updating class definitions at runtime not via monkey patching etc. but via actually changing the class and updating instances) however you pay some dispatch cost on this.

For what it's worth, I've used CL in the past for research code requiring numerical efficiency, i.e. simulations of a different sort.  It works well for me.  In that case I wasn't worried about using existing code -- it didn't exist, so I was writing pretty much everything from scratch anyway.

In summary, it could be a fine choice of language for this project, but not the only one.  If you don't use a language with both high-level aspects and good performance (like CL has, as does OCaml, and a few others) I would definitely look at the possibility of a two level approach with a language like lua or perhaps python (lots of libs) on top of some c or c++ code doing the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the game or simulator industry you find a lot of **C++** plus maybe some added scripting component. There can also be tools written in other languages for scenery design or related tasks. But there is only very little Lisp used in that domain. You need to be a good hacker to get the necessary performance out of Lisp and to be able to access or write the low-level code. How do you get this knowhow? Try, fail, learn, try, fail less, learn, ... There is nothing but writing code and experimenting with it. Lisp is really useful for good software engineers or those that have the potential to be a good software engineer.

One of the main obstacles is the **garbage collector**. Either you have a very simple one (then you have a performance problem with random pauses) or you have a sophisticated one (then you have a problem getting it working right). Only few garbage collectors exist that would be suitable - most Lisp implementations have good GC implementations, but still those are not tuned for real-time or near real-time use. Exceptions do exist. With C++ you can forget the GC, because there usually is none.

The other alternative to automatic memory management with a garbage collector is to use no GC and manage memory 'manually'. This is used by some (even commercial) Lisp applications that need to support some real-time response (for example process control expert systems).

The nearest thing that was developed in that area was the **Crash Bandicoot** (and also later games) game for the Playstation I (later games were for the Playstation II) from Naughty Dog. Since they have been bought by Sony, they switched to C++ for the Playstation III. Their development environment was written in Allegro Common Lisp and it included a compiler for a Scheme (a Lisp dialect) variant. On the development system the code gets compiled and then downloaded to the Playstation during development. They had their own 3d engine (very impressive, always got excellent reviews from game magazines), incremental level loading, complex behaviour control for lots of different actors, etc. So the Playstation was really executing the Scheme code, but memory management was not done via GC (afaik). They had to develop all the technology on their own - nobody was offering Lisp-based tools - but they could, because their were excellent software developers. Since then I haven't heard of a similar project. Note that this was not just Lisp for scripting - it was Lisp all the way down.

One the Scheme side there is also a new interesting implementation called [Ypsilon Scheme](http://www.littlewingpinball.net/mediawiki/index.php/Ypsilon). It is developed for a pinball game - this could be the base for other games, too.

On the Common Lisp side, there have been Lisp applications talking to flight simulators and controlling aspects of them. There are some game libraries that are based on SDL. There are interfaces to OpenGL. There is also something like the 'Open Agent Engine'. There are also some 3d graphics applications written in Common Lisp - even some complex ones. But in the area of flight simulation there is very little prior art.

On the topic of CLOS vs. Functional Programming. Probably one would use neither. If you need to squeeze all possible performance out of a system, then CLOS already has some overheads that one might want to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Functional Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming).  There are a number of frameworks for this in Haskell (don't know about other languages), most of which are based around arrows.  The basic idea is to represent relationships between time-varying values and events.  So for example you would write (in Haskell arrow notation using no particular library):

```
   velocity <- {some expression of airspeed, heading, gravity etc.}
   position <- integrate <- velocity
```

The second line declares the relationship between position and velocity.  The <- arrow operators are syntactic sugar for a bunch of library calls that tie everything together.

Then later on you might say something like:

```
   groundLevel <- getGroundLevel <- position
   altitude <- getAltitude <- position
   crashed <- liftA2 (<) altitude groundLevel
```

to declare that if your altitude is less than the ground level at your position then you have crashed.  Just as with the other variables here, "crashed" is not just a single value, its a time-varying stream of values.  That is why the "liftA2" function is used to "lift" the comparison operator from simple values to streams.

IO is not a problem in this paradigm.  Inputs are time varying values such as joystick X and Y, while the image on the screen is simply another time varying value.  At the very top level your entire simulator is an arrow from the inputs to the outputs.  Then you call a "run" function that converts the arrow into an IO action that runs the game.

If you write this in Lisp you will probably find yourself creating a bunch of macros that basically re-invent arrows, so it might be worth just finding out about arrows to start with.

Comment: Very interesting approach. I'd considered it would involve a lot more code for Haskell (well I guess that's happening below the sugar, but still, quite clean)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about flight sims, and you haven't listed anything in particular they consist of, so this is mostly a guess about writing a FS in Lisp.

Why not:

- Lisp excels at exploratory programming.  I think that since FSs been around so long, and there are free and open-source examples, that it would not benefit as much from this type of programming.
- Flight sims are mostly (I'm guessing) written in static, natively compiled languages.  If you're looking for pure runtime performance, in Lisp this tends to mean type declarations and other not-so-Lispy constructs.  If you don't get the performance you want with naive approaches, your optimized-Lisp might end up looking a lot like C, and Lisp isn't as good at C at writing C.
- A lot of a FS, I'm guessing, is interfacing to a graphics library like OpenGL, which is written in C.  Depending on how your FFI / OpenGL bindings are, this might, again, make your code look like C-in-Lisp.  You might not have the big win that Lisp does in, say, a web app (which consists of generating a tree structure of plain text, which Lisp is great at).

Why:

- I took a glance at the FlightGear source code, and I see a lot of structural boilerplate -- even a straight port might end up being half the size.
- They use strings for keys all over the place (C++ doesn't have symbols).  They use XML for semi-human-readable config files (C++ doesn't have a runtime reader).  Simply switching to native Lisp constructs here could be big win for minimal effort.
- Nothing looks at all complex, even the "AI".  It's simply a matter of keeping everything organized, and Lisp will be great at this because it'll be a lot shorter.

But the neat thing about Lisp is that it's multi-paradigm.  You can use OO for organizing the "objects", and FP for computation within each object.  I say just start writing and see where it takes you.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say functional programming lends itself particularly well to flight simulation. In general, functional languages *can* be very useful for writing scientific simulations, though this is a slightly specialised case. Really, you'd probably be better off with a standard imperative (preferably OOP) language like C++/C#/Java, as they would tend to have the better physics libraries as well as graphics APIs, both of which you would need to use very heavily. Also, the OOP approach might make it easier to represent your environment. Another point to consider is that (as far as I know) the popular flight simulators on the market today are written pretty much entirely in C++.

Essentially, my philosophy is that if there's no particularly good reason that you should need to use functional paradigms, then don't use a functional language (though there's nothing to stop you using functional constructs in OOP/mixed languages). I suspect you're going to have a lot less painful of a development process using the well-tested APIs for C++ and languages more commonly associated with game development (which has many commonalities with flight sim). Now, if you want to add some complex AI to the simulator, Lisp might seem like a rather more obvious choice, though even then I wouldn't at all jump for it. And finally, if you're really keen on using a functional language, I would recommend you go with one of the more general purpose ones like Python or even F# (both mixed imperative-functional languages really), as opposed to Lisp, which could end up getting rather ugly for such a project.

Comment: I'm sure that I didn't ask my question in the most clear way possible, but I believe I will choose this as the answer because it addresses the question that I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I would first think of the nature of the simulation.

Some simulations require interaction like a flight simulator. I don't think functional programming may be a good choice for an interactive (read: CPU intensive/response-critical) applicaiton. Of course, if you have access to 8 PS3's wired together with Linux, you'll not care too much about performance.

For simulations like evolutionary/genetic programming where you set it up and let 'er rip, a functioonal lauguage may help model the problem domain better than an OO language. Not that I'm an expert in functional programming but the ease of coding recursion and the idea of lazy evaluation common in functional languages seems to me a good fit for the 'let her rip' sort of sims.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with functional languages, and that is they don't mesh well with state, but they do go well with process. So in a way it could be said they are action oriented. This means you'll be wasting your time simulating a plane, what you want to do is simulate the actions of flying a plane. Once you grim that you can probably get it to work.

Now as side point, haskell wouldn't be good IMHO, because it's too abstract for a "game", this sort of app is all about Input/Output, but Haskell is about avoiding IO, so it'll become a monad nightmare, and you'll be working against the language. Lisp is a better choice, or Lua or Javascript, they are also functional, but not purely functional, so for your case try Lisp. Anyways in any of these languages your graphics will be C or C++.

A serious issue however is there is very little documentation, and less tutorials about Functional languages and "games", of course scientific simulations is academically documented but those papers are quite dense, if you succeed maybe you could write you experiences, for others as it's a rather empty field right now

Comment: There is no problem writing a game in Haskell.  See my answer below for suggestions about how to do it.

Comment: Haskell (or each pure functional language) is not about avoiding IO: is about confining IO in a way it remains not harmful.